# Add the google map link with longitude and latitude to show at html

Tags: google-maps, location

i save my latitude and longitude into a id, then i want it link to my google map
[image]

I only know to show the google map link, but it's possible that when I change the latitude and longitude each time then when i click the link it will show the location that I want.

Comment: I've inlined your image. Please [edit] your post and paste the HTML as text, not as image

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```html
<td>
  Latitude: <u id="lat1">46.10522</u><br>
  Longitude: <u id="long1">108.616216</u><br>
  <a id="goMap" href="https://www.google.com/maps" target="_blank">Click here to access Google Map</a>
 </td>

 <script>
  var goMap = document.getElementById("goMap")
  goMap.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   this.setAttribute( "href",
          "https://www.google.com/maps/?q=" +
          document.getElementById("lat1").textContent + "," +
          document.getElementById("long1").textContent);
  });
 </script>
```